# VM does not load installed linux

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I run windows 10 on my host and Ubuntu 16.04 on my VM. I programmed a development board and left it running communicating with the VM in order to debug. The dev board is a nodemcu esp8266 and is programmed and communicates via serial port using a USB to uart converter. I was programming it on the VM because I was using esp-open-rtos.

Everything was working perfectly until the power went down. It had a serial converter connected to the VM. Now I can't get to the login screen and there are no graphics, and when I insert my login credentials it welcomes me to ubuntu informs me about the available updates but immediately logs me out, I was only able to see the welcome text because I recorded it and played it back frame by frame. The thing is that I see the ubuntu logo and the dots below blinking .. like it was trying to load the OS, but something goes wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the development board have any software installed on it?  If so, what storage medium does it use?   I have seen flash devices fail after an unexpected power outage quite a lot.  So the Ubuntu VM is running in Windows 10, and being used to debug your dev board, correct?

Comment: @Richie086 It's running freertos ... it's not a linux board and it has an SPI flash on it, it was communicating with the VM via serial port. And yes .... I was using the VM to debug AND flash the board ... the SDK I'm using was made to develop using linux